# Problem in summing only "Numbers" values of a nested object

Tags: javascript, sum, nested-object

Write a function sumValues that accepts an object of nested objects, and returns the sum of all the numerical values in all the levels.

"I am a student and I am learning Javascript" Not allowed to use fancey 1-2 lines functions yet :P

My code so far:

```
const getDepth = function (obj) {
  let depth=0

  while(obj.nextObj){
    depth+=1
    obj=obj.nextObj
  }

  return "The depth of this nested object is equal to " + depth
}
const nestedObject = {
  value1: 10,
  value2: 20,
  nextObj: {
    value3: 11,
    value4: "hello",
    nextObj: {
      value5: "12",
      value6: 8,
      nextObj: {
        value7: 19,
        nextObj: {},
      },
    },
  },
};

const sumValues = function (object) {
   var depth =0; // i deffinetly need to use depth?
  let sum= 0;
  while (nestedObject.nextObj && depth<=4) {
    
    for (const key in object){
    
       if(typeof object[key]==="number"){ 
       
       console.log (object[key])
       sum += object[key]
       depth = depth +1
     }
      else if (typeof object[key]==="object"){
       //object[key]= sumValues(object[key])
      
       sum += sumValues(object[key]);
       depth = depth +1
      }   //&&typeof object[key]!== {} WHERE DO I PUT THIS
      
      }
      return sum
   }  
   
  };
```

Thanks for everyone that helped

TestCase :
sumValues(nestedObject);  // expected output should be => 68

working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively call `sumValues` again when the value itself is an object.

```js
const nestedObject={value1: 10, value2: 20, nextObj: {value3: 11,value4: "hello",nextObj:{value5:"12",value6:8,nextObj:{value7:19,nextObj:{}, },},},};

const sumValues = function (object) {
  let sum= 0;
  for (const key in object){
   if(typeof object[key]==="number"){
     console.log (object[key]) 
     sum = object[key] +sum;
     } else if(typeof object[key] === 'object'){
        sum += sumValues(object[key]);
     }
   }
  return sum
};
console.log('Sum:', sumValues(nestedObject));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was just reading about recurssion although I am not allowed to use it just yet..
Because we are going to study reccursion next week. it can only be done recursively ?

Comment: @Adam.M Either use recursion or a stack/queue.

Comment: Thank you for your input and time :) you helped alot!

Comment: @Adam.M Happy to help.

Comment: @Adam.M The issue is that you're hardcoding the number of levels to 2. That's a problem with not using recursion.

Comment: looks like my code is looping on the first two values twice :P..

Answer (score 0):

Since I am hardcoding the number of levels, I have to find the depth of the givven object.
I made a seperate function for that and I added a testcase for it in the whileloop
Code worked fine after that

Code above is updated and working fine

Comment: You're still using recursion anyway.